# Standard Stream and Operating Systems

Tags: java, c++, c, operating-system

I am very much confused about Streams.

1) Does OS(i.e Windows) provide a Common Standard Input Stream and all the languages use it(i.e. Java refers to it as System.in and same Standard Input Stream is referred with stdin in c)?

Is it like keyboard has some port or physical address and OS has stored that
in some variable and when a program needs that it will give that same address to stdin or System.in depending on the language?

OR,

2) Is it like each language has its own API written for standard streams and when we run the program, a stream will get connected to the input device?

And what information that stream would have apart from data? i.e. Physical Port or address of device or what?

Also, Please tell about what is the meaning of System.in get "connected" to program when we run it. what does "connected" mean here?

Please share some link.

Comment: File Descriptor 1 is created for the process before it starts, and anything written to that is written to the standard output.

Comment: The answer is highly system specific. These days most people are used to Windoze and Eunuch-style brain damaged I/O that is highly limited.

Answer (score 5):

#### Definitions

A “stream” is a catch-all word, like “window”. All a stream means is that there is some thing (a “device”) that produces sequential data or accepts sequential data.

For example, I can make a string into an input stream (produces data), by simply keeping track of what the next character to produce is. When we run out of characters, we've reached the end of the stream. C++:

```
struct my_hello_stream
{
  static const char* s = "Hello world!";
  int n;
  my_stream(): n(0) {}

  int get()
  {
    if (s[n]) return s[n++];
    return EOF;
  }
};
```

#### Abstractions

Every system has its own way of abstracting a stream. The OS does it through *files*, *pipes* and *character devices*, which you can open for reading or writing. How exactly this is done depends entirely on the design of the OS. Consult your OS API documentation.

On top of that sits a programming language, like C or C++ or Java or FORTRAN — you name it. The programming language itself *also* defines a stream in a way convenient for the users of that language. In C you have a `FILE*`. In C++ you have `std::iostream`s. In Java you have [I/O streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). Whatever the case, this works above the OS stream to read and write data from and to files, etc.

Moreover, these language features often allow you to do more powerful things with these stream interfaces, such as convert the character sequence `1234567` into a native integer value, and to perform these operations over strings.

Beyond that, there are also external libraries that allow us to treat things like internet connections and port connections with the printer like a stream. Some of this stuff the OS handles for us. Some of it it doesn't.

#### tl;dr

It all depends. What matters is the *abstraction* you have access to — which is typically your programming language. Hence, read about how your programming language expects you to open a file and read and write data, then act as if that is right. Whatever else actually happens underneath is magic.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. First I could not understand all this. But after looking at various blogs, now I understood what you meant. It was high level explanation for me but to the point.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a stream?**

Stream is an abstraction which is either an input source or an output destination. In UNIX for example everything is a file so your keyboard will be represented by a read only file (why?). Whenever you want to read something from keyboard you just use the read system call using the keyboard file as parameter.

> Does OS(i.e Windows) provide a Common Standard Input Stream and all
>   the languages use it(i.e. Java refers to it as System.in and same
>   Standard Input Stream is referred with stdin in c)?

OS only provides the very basic functionality such as read and write system calls (OS dependent) which can be used to read and write raw bytes. All the programming languages use this basic functionality to create abstractions (such as translating raw bytes to certain character set or buffering the data before writing).

Comment: I have one more question, Is it like System.in read from a device( and that part is abstracted and use System calls like read(OS dependent)) and then when we use read(), we read from the System.in stream? Or System.in.read() invokes the system call? Please take a look at this link: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/inputOutput.html

Comment: I don't think i understand first part of your question but answer to the second part is yes.

Comment: First part is regarding the link and your answer, in that link it is mentioned that Input stream reads the data coming from the device and then our program reads the bytes/ characters from that Input Stream when we use Syste.in.read method. So that suggests that it is a two step process.

Comment: Suppose I am entering Input "Hi", then according to that link, first Input Stream would read the input from device and this step itself would make system call(read function of OS) and then in the second step when we call System.in.read() of Java I/O API then we would read from InputStream. So is it a 2 step process? Or it is a single step process i.e. when we call System.in.read() then itself system call would be invoked to read the input from device?

Answer (score 0):

When the program starts executing operating systems opens three standard text stream (channel) automatically and provides constant file pointer for them.
The stream you can think as like a channel, rather than a standard stream we have to open a stream by some library functions like fopen in c, which creates a stream bw your program and the file specified.